# Thread main Suspended

Tags: java

my code is given below and i hav created a user class also

```
 package com.glomindz.mercuri.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.glomindz.mercuri.pojo.User;
import com.glomindz.mercuri.util.MySingleTon;

 public class UserServicesDAO {

private Connection connection;

public UserServicesDAO() {
    // connection = new MySingleTon().getConnection();
    connection = MySingleTon.getInstance().getConnection();

}

public List<User> get_all_data() {
    List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM spl_user_master";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        boolean execute = stmt.execute();
        System.out.println(execute);
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
        System.out.println(resultSet.getMetaData());
        while (resultSet.next()) {
                    User user  = new User();
                    user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                    user.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
                    user.setMobile(resultSet.getString("mobile"));
                    user.setPassword(resultSet.getString("password"));
                    user.setRole(resultSet.getString("role"));
                    user.setStatus(resultSet.getString("status"));
                    user.setLast_udpate(resultSet.getString("last_update"));

                    // print the results
                    System.out.println(user);
                    usersList.add(user);
                }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new UserServicesDAO().get_all_data();
}
```

}

i got the output, only `last_update` gives me `null` value. I have changed it to timestamp but no effect...in the debug gives me error:

```
Thread main suspended
UserServicesDAO.get_all_data() line24
UserServicesDAO.main(String[]) line56
```

what's the problem plz give me a solution..

Comment: What is your problem? From the given information we are not able to determine where your real problem is. Is there an `Exception`? Does it not yield the result you want? Where is the sentence `Thread main suspended` displayed?

Comment: That does not look like an error message. It looks more like a message given by a debugger when it stops at a breakpoint which you have set on line 24...

Comment: Don't edit my answer. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I see only two reasons for `user.last_update` to be null:

1. It's null in the database. Check your data. Check that everything is committed. Check that you're querying the correct database.
2. `setLast_update()` doesn't actually set the field `last_update` field. Show us the code of `User` to confirm or infirm.

Also, please respect the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your database. Make sure resultSet is returning the right type.

For example:

```
resultSet.getInt("id");
```

might be

```
resultSet.getLong("id");
```

this can cause you troubles. At least this happened to me once. You should check for other fields name,email,mobile.

Also be careful about date

```
resultSet.getString("last_update")
```

if in your database "last_update" column  type is not string, this can also cause you problems